# Интеграция Content API в Битрикс

Tags: php, api, битрикс

Появилась необходимость интегрировать в интернет-магазин на битриксе ContentAPI для синхронизации фида с Google Merchant, поискал по гуглу, официальные мануалы, но ничего конкретного не нашел, все мануалы для самописных движков или конкретных CRM, а для Битрикса ничего нет, может была у кого подобная задача? Что, куда и как интегрировать?)
Есть ли какие-то конкретные мануалы, ибо опыта уж очень мало с PHP и CRM в принципе.

Comment: Мануал про интеграцию импорта-экспорта не помог?

Comment: К сожалению - нет, ничего конкретного не нашел

Comment: По этому мануалу, да и без него, а по аналогии с коробочным импортом можно же сделать какой угодно импорт. Открывайте штатный файл и изучайте. Под ключ вам все равно никто жевать не будет.

Comment: https://marketplace.bitrix.ua/solutions/wisesolutions.wsexport/

Рекомендую